# read an external worksheet using apache poi in java

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to create an excel which has the names. I need to execute a formula which needs to reference an external worksheet.

```
String formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,[asd.xlsx]Sheet1!B$2:L$2045,11,0)";

               System.out.println("formula: "+formula);
               cell1.setCellFormula(formula);
```

When I execute this, I get the following exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: not implemented yet
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getExternalSheetIndex(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:127)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.createAreaRefParseNode(FormulaParser.java:615)
```

I tried to use INDIRECT function, set that formula as text and execute the INDIRECT, but it did not work. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Update 1:

Thanks for the comments. I did not use XSSFEEvaluationWorkbook. My code is below

```
       FileInputStream abc = new FileInputStream(new File("Z_abc.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbookabc = new XSSFWorkbook(abc);
        XSSFSheet sheetabc = workbookabc.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> rowIteratorRead = sheetabc.iterator();

        while (rowIteratorRead.hasNext())
        {
            Row rowRead = rowIteratorRead.next();

            if(rowRead.getRowNum()==0){
                continue;
            }//if(row.getRowNum()==0){


            Cell cell = rowRead.getCell(0);


            Cell cell1 =  rowRead.getCell(1); //////////////////////////
            if(cell1 == null) {
               cell1 =rowRead.createCell(1);

               int rowNumber = (rowRead.getRowNum()+1);

               String formula = "VLOOKUP(A2,[asd.xlsx]Sheet1!B$2:L$2045,11,0)";

               //System.out.println("formula: "+formula);
               cell1.setCellFormula(formula);
               //cell1.setCellValue(formula);

            }//if(cell1 == null) {  

        }//while (rowIteratorRead.hasNext())
```

I was successful in getting the formulas work if they refer from same workbook without using XSSFEEvaluationWorkbook.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you initialize everything? [XSSFEvaluationWorkbook](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.html) You need to show a little more code.

Comment: What's about _RuntimeException: not implemented yet_. Are you sure that apache poi has this feature?

Comment: I have updated my original question with additional code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Divers, that is what I am confused about. I saw different replies for this and I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Any suggestions? Thanks.